# Failed to created module context in Android

Tags: android

I am implementing a QR Code scanner in Android from a fragment.

This is the primary activity method that calls the fragment:

```
case R.id.buttonPrint:
        fragment_QrScan qrFragment = new fragment_QrScan();
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction1 = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction1.replace(R.id.qrContainer, qrFragment).commit();
        break;
```

This is in the fragment

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        thiscontext = container.getContext();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout._fragment_qr_scan, container, false);

        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) view.findViewById(R.id.surfaceViewQr);
        textViewMessage = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewMessage);

        barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(thiscontext)
                .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.QR_CODE).build();

        cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(thiscontext, barcodeDetector)
                .setRequestedPreviewSize(150,150).build();

        surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                try{
                    cameraSource.start(surfaceView.getHolder());
                }catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                cameraSource.stop();
            }
        });

        barcodeDetector.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<Barcode>() {
            @Override
            public void release() {

            }

            @Override
            public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
                final SparseArray<Barcode> qrCodes = detections.getDetectedItems();

                if(qrCodes.size() != 0) {
                    textViewMessage.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                            vibrator.vibrate(1000);
                            textViewMessage.setText(qrCodes.valueAt(0).displayValue);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

On the

```
barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(thiscontext)
                .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.QR_CODE).build();
```

I get this error:

> 01-16 17:31:45.127 18330-18330/com.jiebao.demos
>   E/DynamiteLoaderV2Impl: Failed to create module context.
>       java.io.IOException: Exception while loading config file descriptor
>           at bo.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamiteloader@19831046@19.8.31
>   (040306-0):63)
>           at bo.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamiteloader@19831046@19.8.31
>   (040306-0):21)
>           at com.google.android.gms.dynamiteloader.DynamiteLoaderV2.loadModule2NoCrashUtils(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamiteloader@19831046@19.8.31
>   (040306-0):34)
>           at bk.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamiteloader@19831046@19.8.31
>   (040306-0):17)
>           at e.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamiteloader@19831046@19.8.31
>   (040306-0):5)
>           at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:392)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.common.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
>           at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.zzl.zzb(Unknown Source)
>           at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.zzb(Unknown Source)
>           at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.zza(Unknown Source)
>           at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.load(Unknown Source)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzr.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common@@19.0.0:12)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzn.zzp(com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common@@19.0.0:39)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzh.(com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision@@19.0.0:3)
>           at com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.BarcodeDetector$Builder.build(com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision@@19.0.0:7)
>           at com.jiebao.demos.AutomatedTicketingSystem.NewTicketing.fragment_QrScan.onCreateView(fragment_QrScan.java:57)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5737)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean
>   java.lang.String.contains(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object
>   reference
>           at android.content.ContentResolver.checkLeakDetectIgnoreList(ContentResolver.java:2695)
>           at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1178)
>           at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:958)
>           at android.content.ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:811)
>           at android.content.ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:765)
>           at bo.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamiteloader@19831046@19.8.31
>   (040306-0):61)
>           at bo.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamiteloader@19831046@19.8.31
>   (040306-0):21) 
>           at com.google.android.gms.dynamiteloader.DynamiteLoaderV2.loadModule2NoCrashUtils(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamiteloader@19831046@19.8.31
>   (040306-0):34) 
>           at bk.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamiteloader@19831046@19.8.31
>   (040306-0):17) 
>           at e.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamiteloader@19831046@19.8.31
>   (040306-0):5) 
>           at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:392) 
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.common.zza.zza(Unknown Source) 
>           at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.zzl.zzb(Unknown Source) 
>           at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.zzb(Unknown Source) 
>           at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.zza(Unknown Source) 
>           at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.load(Unknown Source) 
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzr.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common@@19.0.0:12) 
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzn.zzp(com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common@@19.0.0:39) 
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzh.(com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision@@19.0.0:3) 
>           at com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.BarcodeDetector$Builder.build(com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision@@19.0.0:7) 
>           at com.jiebao.demos.AutomatedTicketingSystem.NewTicketing.fragment_QrScan.onCreateView(fragment_QrScan.java:57) 
>           at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439) 
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460) 
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784) 
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852) 
>           at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802) 
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625) 
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411) 
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366) 
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273) 
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733) 
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5737) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)  01-16
>   17:31:45.130 18330-18330/com.jiebao.demos E/Vision: Error loading
>   module com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode optional module true
>       com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$LoadingException: Remote load failed. No local fallback found.
>           at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.load(Unknown Source)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzr.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common@@19.0.0:12)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzn.zzp(com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common@@19.0.0:39)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzh.(com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision@@19.0.0:3)
>           at com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.BarcodeDetector$Builder.build(com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision@@19.0.0:7)
>           at com.jiebao.demos.AutomatedTicketingSystem.NewTicketing.fragment_QrScan.onCreateView(fragment_QrScan.java:57)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5737)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
>        Caused by: com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$LoadingException:
>   Failed to get module context
>           at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.zzb(Unknown Source)
>           at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.zza(Unknown Source)
>           at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.load(Unknown Source)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzr.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common@@19.0.0:12) 
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzn.zzp(com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common@@19.0.0:39) 
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzh.(com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision@@19.0.0:3) 
>           at com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.BarcodeDetector$Builder.build(com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision@@19.0.0:7) 
>           at com.jiebao.demos.AutomatedTicketingSystem.NewTicketing.fragment_QrScan.onCreateView(fragment_QrScan.java:57) 
>           at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439) 
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460) 
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784) 
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852) 
>           at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802) 
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625) 
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411) 
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366) 
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273) 
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733) 
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5737) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)